# Run time check error 3 in case

Tags: c++, c

I have the program half way figured out except when I go to cube a number/square a number/display odd or even without entering a number, instead of it simply stating "You have not entered a number" I get a run check error #3 then a really large negative number. This is obviously not what I want to happen.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


//begin function
int main ()
{

//declare variables
int choice;
int number = 0;
int cubed;
int squared;

//menu and begin do while loop
do {


printf("***********************\n");
printf("--Main Menu---\n");
printf("***********************\n");
printf("1.Enter a number\n");
printf("2.Cube the number\n");
printf("3.Square the number\n");
printf("4.Display Even or Odd\n");
printf("5.Quit\n");

printf("Enter your choice:   ");
scanf("%i", &choice);

printf("Your current number is: %i \n", number);

//begin switch and functions
switch(choice){

 case 1: 
      printf("Enter a number\n");
      scanf("%i", &number);
break;

case 2:  

      if (number == 0)
      printf("You have not entered a number\n");
      else 
      cubed= number * number * number;
      printf("Your number cubed is: %i \n", cubed);
break;

case 3:
       if (number == 0)
       printf("You have not entered a number\n");
       else
       squared=  number * number;
       printf("Your number squared is: %i \n", squared);
break;
case 4:
      if (number == 0)
       printf("You have not entered a number\n");
       else if
      (number % 2 ==0)
      printf("Your number squared is even!\n");

      else 

      printf("Your number is odd!\n");

break;

case 5:
      printf("Goodbye!!!!\n");
system("pause");
break;

default:
      printf("Was not 1 through 5\n");
break;
}// end switch and functions








} while (choice!=5); 


} //end function
```

Comment: It works here: http://ideone.com/TagkqI

Comment: @karma_geek: undefined behaviours may ostensibly work some of the time... there's still a real issue as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: @Session: you should check for success when calling `scanf`, e.g. `if (scanf("%I", &number) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "your input wasn't a valid number\n"); exit(1); }`, otherwise someone typing e.g. letters or punctuation won't be warned.

Answer (score 2):

GIGO aka Garbage in garbage out. (Or more accurately "undefined behavior")

You never set `number` (so it has some random value), but your `if` statements  check `number` as if it had a default value of < 0. Try setting `number`'s default like this: `int number = -1;`

Comment: The test is actually for `number < 0`, so setting to `0` wouldn't work (need e.g. `-1` or `INT_MIN`), but get my vote for pointing out the general problem anyway.

Comment: Am i missing something? when i define the variable int number = -1; it still does the same thing. Even switching the if statements to (number ==0) then defining int number = 0; still causes the same error. I am sorry I feel like I am missing something really obvious, I am very new to programming.

Comment: You need to show your edited code with `int number = -1;` Try printing the value of `number` before your `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

C does not initialize variables so you will have to do it. If yo don't initialize you're variable will be equal whatever is at the memory location so it is unpredictable. In your case you should initialize number with negative value  to force entering a number first. int number=-1;

Answer (score 2):

Set a default value for number like -1 or any negative number. Then your code will work fine.